# Несколько попапов на странице

Tags: javascript, html

У меня на странице имеются 2 модальных окна и 2 кнопки.
При нажатие на "Открыть 1" должен открыть первое модальное окно, при нажатие на 2 кнопку должен открыть второе модальное окно. Я написал скрипт, но он работает не так. При нажатие на любую кнопку класс добавляется ко всем модальным окнам. Как можно сделать так чтобы класс добавлял только для определенного модального окна?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .popap{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left:50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: red;
      display: none;
    }
    .active {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button  class="open">Открыть1</button>
  <button  class="open">Открыть2</button>
  <div class="popap" id="popap">
    <h1>Ку1</h1>
    <button id="delete" class="delete">Убрать</button>
  </div>
  <div class="popap" id="popap">
    <h1>Ку2</h1>
    <button id="delete" class="delete">Убрать</button>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
  let opens = document.querySelectorAll('.open')
  let deletes = document.querySelectorAll('.delete')
  let popas = document.querySelectorAll('.popap')


  opens.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      popas.forEach(popap => {
        popap.classList.add('active')
      })
    })
  });

  deletes.forEach(button =>{
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      popas.forEach(popap => {
        popap.classList.remove('active')
      })
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`popas` - не самое удачное наименование в русском сегменте %))

`popups` - корректнее.

```js
let opens = document.querySelectorAll('.open')
let deletes = document.querySelectorAll('.delete')
let popas = document.querySelectorAll('.popap')


opens.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
    popas[i].classList.add('active');
  })
});

deletes.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
    popas[i].classList.remove('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.popap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="open">Открыть1</button>
<button class="open">Открыть2</button>
<div class="popap" id="popap">
  <h1>Ку1</h1>
  <button id="delete" class="delete">Убрать</button>
</div>
<div class="popap" id="popap">
  <h1>Ку2</h1>
  <button id="delete" class="delete">Убрать</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает. А не можете рассказать как тут используется i ? Я бы понял примерно если в html у попапов был их собственный id и i ссылался на них.

Comment: А, все понял кажись.

Comment: popas неплохо звучит кстати.

Comment: @Aarnihauta хах, не много забыл как пишется)